# Odd behavior with CSS navigation bar

Tags: css, html

While working on the CSS for a navigation bar, i noticed an odd behavior.

Using:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav li {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The output turns out as expected:

[image: Expected Output]

However, when i combine the two CSS statements:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I get an unexpected block style output:

[image]

If someone could explain this occurrence to me that'd be great. Thanks.

Entire (Relevant) CSS:

```css
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0;
}
#nav li {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s background-color;
}
#nav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="\Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="\News.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="\Content.html">Content</a></li>
    <li><a href="\Products.html">Products</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide the associated html and more css?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce what you're claiming given the code you posted.

Comment: CSS is correct! Can you provide your HTML??

Comment: Found the issue. Turns out i was putting `display: inline-block;` into the `#nav ul` instead of `#nav li`. My apologies for the simple mistake.

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yapr9xu5/)

This does not give unexpected block style output.

Comment: Yeah, i assumed i had put `display: inline-block;` into `#nav li` (Which is why i wrote it as such in my question, while actually it was in the `ul` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I wasn't combining the two `#nav li`'s, it turns out i was combining one `#nav li` and the `#nav ul`.